# Story about a weather-controlling machine in an english village

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm trying to find the title of a graphic novel (or perhaps a book) I read in the 90's that took place in a remote village in northern England.

The strange thing about this village was that there was a weather-controlling device that was beneath a cricket field. You followed a long/windy cave path and found a large cavern with a stone-work device that was built by aliens (or Atlantisians), and it used some sort of ion mechanics to use the water table as some sort of antenna to control the cloud formations through all of England.

There was a lot of talk about how Stonehenge was meant to be a counter-balance to control the seas, or the night, or something like that.

The main plot was that the Queen already knew about this device, yet the CIA was trying to control (possibly study/reproduce) it to manipulate the weather patterns over Kansas.  Actually, maybe Kansas was in the title.

Hope someone remembers this! Would love to re-read, and see if any other stories evolved out of the universe.

Comment: I don't know the story, but it brings to my mind [this song and video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRHA9W-zExQ). Was Orgonon or Orgone mentioned?

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118661/ ?